# Матушка-земля (-природа, -Россия, -Волга), но матушка государыня (игуменья, настоятельница, царица), - почему?

Tags: раздельно-дефис, сложные-слова

Почему "матушка" то с дефисом, то без? Есть ли правило?

Словарь себе противоречит (см. матушка-Русь - матушка Россия):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово ***матушка*** может использоваться **как обращение и как приложение**. Также это слово может относиться **к нарицательному и собственному имени**. Все эти варианты надо различать.

По общим правилам Розенталя **обращение  пишется раздельно** (сравнить: товарищ, гражданин, госпожа и т.д.).

Написание приложения **зависит от позиции для имен собственных**: раздельно перед именем собственным и через дефис после него.

Приложения, отнесенные **к нарицательному существительному**, пишутся через дефис в любой позиции, но **раздельное написание как исключение** для приложений с качественным (определительным) значением (красавица невеста),  в ПАС этого исключения нет.

**И что мы тогда имеем:**

матушка Россия, матушка Русь, Россия-матушка, Русь-матушка, Волга-матушка;

лень-матушка, матушка-природа, земля-матушка, матушка-земля, деревня-матушка;

матушка царица, матушка игуменья (обращения), у матушки царицы (определительное значение приложения);

Розенталь допускает написание **матушка-Русь** как устойчивое. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

При наличии **определения** возможно дефисное написание: наша матушка-Россия.

**Примеры:**

Ох, ты **Русь-матушка**… И впрямь ― умом тебя понять невозможно.  [«Криминальная хроника», 2003.07.24]

Люди были Неясны самим себе. Ах ты, **матушка Россия,** что ты делаешь со мной? То ли все вокруг смурные? То ли я один смурной? [Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007)]

А прирост населения в полтора раза увеличился. Опять отдувается **деревня-матушка**. Не хотим мы рожать в городе, и всё тут. [Василий Шукшин. Печки-лавочки (1970-1972)]

Он улыбнулся. ― Подождите, война кончится победой, и тогда интернационалисты объявят: " **Наша матушка-Россия** всему свету голова".  [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, ч. 1 (1960)]

Сами поверили в свой титанизм. Ты же угодлива, ты и завистлива, **матушка Русь.** Сложный характер. В такой дихотомии вся ее сласть. [Леонид Зорин. Глас народа (2007-2008) // «Знамя», 2008]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147762/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.